# x64 application is not attaching to Visual studio isolated shell

Tags: c#, .net

I have a sample C# application,

When i attach this application to VS Isolated shell 2013 for debugging, it is working fine when application platform target is x86.

But it is failing to attach to VS Isolated shell when application platform target is x64

*Error message showing when attaching to x64 application*

> Unable to attach to the process. The debugger is not properly
>   installed.  Run setup to install or repair the debugger

Does VS Isolataed shell support x64 application debugging?

If so how can i fix this issue?

Comment: FYI, I've tried on my PC (Visual Studio 2013) and it works exactly the same way Win32/x64, it should be a kind of setup error as the message says. EDIT: I've read so fast, I am using the full IDE not the isolated shell

Comment: Try to reinstall VS. Also, try to run it with admin privileges.

Comment: When attaching to VS 2013 it is working fine, My issue occurs when i attaching it to VS 2013 isolated shell...It is also not working in admin privilege